# Overlay bitmap on live video

Tags: video, directshow, overlay, msdn

Hi i want to Overlay bitmap on live video. Iam trying to do this with the directshow sample.
I edited PlayCapMonker sample and added some functions to enable this.
i did this with the procedure explained in below link

http://www.ureader.com/msg/1471251.aspx

Now i am gettting errors

Error   2   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   3   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   5   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   6   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   8   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   9   error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   21  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   22  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   26  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   27  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
Error   36  error C2228: left of '.m_alpha' must have class/struct/union
Error   38  error C2227: left of '->SetAlphaBitmap' must point to class/struct/union/generic type
Error   7   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Pool'
Error   4   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'Format'  c:\Program Files\Microsoft Platform SDK\include\Vmr9.h  368 PlayCapMoniker
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Error   20  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
Error   25  error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
Error   30  error C2065: 'g_pMixerBitmap' : undeclared identifier
Error   33  error C2065: 'g_pMixerBitmap' : undeclared identifier
Error   37  error C2065: 'g_pMixerBitmap' : undeclared identifier
Error   31  error C2065: 'g_hbm' : undeclared identifier
Error   32  error C2065: 'g_hbm' : undeclared identifier
Error   35  error C2065: 'config' : undeclared identifier
Error   10  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   11  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   12  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   13  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   16  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   19  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   23  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   24  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   28  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   29  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DSurface9'
Error   14  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DDevice9'
Error   15  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DDevice9'
Error   17  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DDevice9'
Error   18  error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'IDirect3DDevice9'
Error   34  error C2039: 'pDDS' : is not a member of '_VMR9AlphaBitmap' SDK\Samples\Multimedia\DirectShow\Capture\PlayCapMoniker\PlayCapMoniker.cpp 263 PlayCapMoniker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a well-known issue (meaning: google would have been your friend), involving a clash between various header files (qedit.h, d3d9.h, vmr.h). See http://tmhare.mvps.org/faqs.htm#qed for example.

G

content from tmhare's site:
  You probably also have   in your include file list.  This is a known issue and the workaround is to split your code that uses VMR9 and the code that uses DES and related functions like IMediaDet into two separate source files.  This means  that you can't put either header file in a precompiled header such as stdafx.h.

An alternative solution was posted on the newsgroups by chadderack.  He uses the #define below so that the conflicts are avoided:

```
#ifndef __D3DRM_H__
#define __D3DRM_H__
#endif

#include <dshow.h>
#include <d3d9.h>
#include <vmr9.h>
#include <qedit.h>
#include <dxerr9.h>
```

Comment: THe above link is not opening.